# What is the proper style for listing imports in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style

Is it better to list each individual piece of a package you're going to need (see #1) or is it better to just import everything from a package (see #2)?

#### 1

```
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
```

#### 2

```
import java.awt.*;
```

Comment: Probably because it's subjective.

Comment: It's not subjective at all -- see my answer below. Using import-on-demand can result in code that stops compiling as new classes are added to existing packages (think about what happened when they added List to java.util -- everyone who had imported java.awt.* and java.util.* and used List now had code that would not compile.)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's ***NOT*** simply a matter of style; import-on-demand can result in code that ceases to compile as new classes are added to existing packages.

Basic idea
  (See http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html for details.):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
...
List list;
```

worked in Java 1.1; as of Java 1.2, the above code will no longer compile.

Import on demand is ***EVIL*** because your program can stop compiling when new classes are added to existing packages!

***ALWAYS*** use explicit imports. It's not a matter of style; it's a matter of safety.

This is especially bad if you check in perfectly-compiling code and a year later someone checks it out and tries to compile it with new class libraries.

(Import-on-demand is an example of a really bad programming language feature - no feature should break code when new types are added to a system!)

Comment: Also, some modern Java IDEs automatically (or by keystroke) add explicit imports.

Answer (score 26):

Use import individually.

It is way lot better for production code to list each and every one of the classes being imported.

While the IDE's do a great job helping you know which classes are being used, it is more readable to know that you're referring to :

```
java.util.List;
```

and not

```
java.awt.List;
```

and so on.

Additionally it is recommended that you group them by package starting by the core libraries passing by 3rd party and ending with own project libraries:

```
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Date;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

 import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;

 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpec;

 import your.own.packagename.here.SomeClass;
 import your.own.packagename.here.OtherClass;
```

Using wildcard is acceptable for small self project/classes. It is faster, but it is not expected to be maintainable. If any other developer is involved, use the first.

Comment: +1 Good examples. I hope it's not inappropriate to ask: Did you mean to start over? http://stackoverflow.com/users/20654/oscar-reyes v http://stackoverflow.com/users/249231/oscar-reyes

Comment: it looks like he is seeing how much interest (in points) his original profile can gain despite no longer answering questions on it.

Comment: I disagree with organising packages as groups of core, 3rd party and project packages.  It is a common practice but I prefer to list all imports alphabetically.  I find it's easier to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: I find Alt-Enter and Control-Alt-o (JDeveloper) to be faster than typing `import java.util.*` ...

Answer (score 3):

The latter is generally considered "bad form". With tool support, there's no excuse for not listing them individually, and it removes any ambiguity.

Mind you, Eclipse by default uses wildcards for static imports, and explicit imports for normal ones. Not sure why it makes that distinction.

**edit:** the distinction is obvious in hindsight - static imports often refer to static methods, and you can't unambiguously refer to a static method by name (due to overloading). So if it can't be fully unambiguous, you may as well use a wildcard.

Comment: I think part of the point of static imports is to replace inheriting an interface of constants, and if you had to do one at a time imports it would kind of interfere that part of the purpose, so a wild card has more of a place in that case.

Comment: Another good use case is `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`. No, I don't want to import each `assertXXX` individually.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was not about performance but, the [cost of import statements](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm031.shtml) question of the month on [javaperformancetuning.com](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/) perfectly summarize why you should avoid to use wildcards:

> (...)
>   Finally, many people find that using
>   imports with wildcards makes the
>   source much less readable, since the
>   reader also needs to figure out which
>   package a particular class comes from,
>   rather than just looking it up in the
>   import statement.
>
> So the full answer is
>
> - There is no runtime cost from using an import statement
> - The compilation process can take a little more time with an import
>     statement
> - The compilation process can take even more time with a wildcard import
>     statement
> - **For improved readability, wildcard import statements are bad practice for
>     anything but throwaway classes**
> - The compilation overhead of non-wildcard import statements are
>     minor, but **they give readability
>     benefits so best practice is to use
>     them**

It **is** a bad practice to use wilcard import statements,  they make the code less readable, just don't do it. The only exception to this rule are static import, for example `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`. No, I don't want to import each `assertXXX` individually and I don't find that this harms code readability.

Answer (score 2):

If you list them individually it is easier to detect, when reading code with a simple editor (rather than from inside a dev environment), which package objects come from. When reading code from complex projects this can save significant time. Had an example of that earlier today, in fact, when I was studying code from a large open source project without wanting to load everything into eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an ide like visual studio it typically takes care of this issue for you, so you don't even need to bother thinking about it.

Most IDEs that I am aware of choose option 1 above. This is consistent with some code analysis tools that I used in the past (like checkstyle), as they consider it bad practice to use the * notation.

Answer (score 0):

The option 1 you listed is preferable but if there are more classes you are importing from say java.awt.image, then its preferable to just have one import java.awt.image.* Most IDE's let you specify the exact count of the number of imports to be used. For eg in IDEA, we can use `File->Settings->Code Style->imports` In the General tab there is a field `Class count to use import with *` and default value is 5.

Answer (score 0):

whatever the default of your team's IDE is. that way you can just do an autoformat of your file before committing it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no one right answer here.

The People Who Brought You Eclipse voted for individual imports, since Source/Organize Imports will convert the * form to the specific form.

Comment: actually it's a configurable upper limit, ie use * if more than X from same package.

Comment: Unless you use more than 10 imports from the same package, case in which Eclipse uses the *-import type (by default anyway)

Answer (score -1):

Import individually, it saves the compiler from having to look through each package for each class and therefore makes things run quicker.

Comment: It's been a while since I studied this, but I don't believe `import` statements have any effect by the time the JVML code is executed. In the JVML all referenced classes have to be mentioned explicitly. The compiler issue may be valid - I'd be curious to see benchmarks.

Comment: Correct - there is no runtime penalty (though it can make the compiler a wee bit slower to use import-on-demand). Imports are only "aliases" that get expanded in the generated .class file. Explicit imports are directly expanded; import-on-demand forces a search on the classpath to find which qualified type name to include in the .class file)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was always just lead to believe that it made something faster.