# Will using a single file from a package include all files?

Tags: java

If I import and use a single class from another package, will it include all files from the package?

for example, if I use only a single class from the mylibrary package which is called MyFunctions, will the following include all classes or not?

```
import my.example.mylibrary.*;
```

compared with:

```
import my.example.mylibrary.MyFunctions;
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "include"?  Do you mean, will the VM load all those classes at runtime?  If so, I think the answer is "no" but you can run the VM with class loading debug turned on and verify for yourself.

Comment: import != include

Do you come from a C/C++ background?  If so, import can look similar to include, but is actually more similar to the using clause from C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

The import does not include anything into your program.

Classes are loaded when they are used, and not before. So the only thing the `import` is to help you to avoid typing the whole class name.

For instance it is much better to type ( and to read ) :

```
import my.example.mylibrary.SomeClass;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
...
SomeClass some = new SomeClass();
List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
list.add( some );
etc..
```

than

```
// no import 
... 
my.example.mylibrary.SomeClass some = new my.example.mylibrary.SomeClass();
java.util.List<my.example.mylibrary.SomeClass> list = new java.util.ArrayList<my.example.mylibrary.SomeClass>();
list.add( some );
```

And yet, they perform exactly the same.

Also, bear in mind that using

```
import some.packagename.*;
```

vs.

```
import some.packagename.Each;
import some.packagename.Single;
import some.packagename.Class;
import some.packagename.ByLine;
```

Have exactly the same performace, except the firs it faster ( and dirtier )  and the second is clearer.

**Always!!** [use the second form in production and/or when someone else needs to see your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067158/what-is-the-proper-style-for-listing-imports-in-java/2067182#2067182)

Comment: I also think the second way will help with the ambiguity of class names as well. 


For example, in JDK 1.1, there was no java.util.List class. Consider a program that imports java.awt.* and java.util.* and uses the name List as a shortened form of java.awt.List. That program compiles without errors under JDK1.1 but fails to compile in Java 2.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "include"?

The two have no difference in performance. The only thing they do is allow you to write `MyFunctions` instead of `my.example.library.MyFunctions` all the time.

The class loader will (typically) load a `.class` file when you first use that class. When the `.class` is inside a `.jar` file, maybe it will load more than that. But that does not depend on the way you wrote your `import`.

Answer (score 2):

Import statements are only a directive to the compiler to help it resolve references to classes using an unqualified class name - *nothing more*.

For example, every class implicitly imports `java.lang.*`, which means you can refer to `String` instead of `java.lang.String` and `Integer` instead of `java.lang.Integer`, etc.

If you have `mypackage.A` and `mypackage.B` and you `import mypackage.A` you can use `A` in the class but you must use `mypackage.B` instead of just `B`.

Using `*` instead of a specific class name simply tells the compiler to allow all classes in the package instead of a specific one.  So `import mypackage.*` allows you to use `A` and `B` in the code.

Comment: +1 BTW, java.lang is the only package that's automatically "import"'ed  always.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically import MyFunctions, the compiler still will not know about MyOtherFunctions.  The * version will import everything from the package.